# Matrix with special condition

Tags: algorithms

I need to make a square matrix $A\in M_n$. The elements in the matrix are from $1$ to $N$ (inclusive). No integer can appear twice in same row or column.

So is there a formula to calculate values of $A$ in ***i<sup>th</sup>***  row and **j<sup>th</sup>** column for given ***N***.

I need to print the matrix where the distance from the center cell to the nearest $1$ is the maximum.

Distance between $ (x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $|x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2| $

Comment: Well it seems you got the trick.

Comment: Please think carefully before heavily modify a question

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti I'm really sorry.

Comment: @sammy, you mean that distance is $|x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2|$, right?

Comment: @Ennar yes. Sorry didn't notice the error.

Comment: [Code Chef November challenge question](https://www.codechef.com/NOV16/problems/CHSQR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Note: the question was edited, but I left the first part almost unaltered)*

Let $\sigma = (1\,2\ldots\,N)\in S_N$. Then you can define $a_{ij} = \sigma^{N-j}(i)$ to get your matrix. Let us check that entries won't repeat in the same row or column:

$$a_{ij} = a_{ij'} \implies \sigma^{N-j}(i) = \sigma^{N-j'}(i) \implies \sigma^{j-j'}(i) = i$$

but $\sigma^k$ has no fixed point except for $k$ such that $N\mid k$, i.e. $\sigma^k = \operatorname{id}$. This implies $j = j'$.

$$a_{ij} = a_{i'j} \implies \sigma^{N-j}(i) = \sigma^{N-j}(i') \implies i = i'$$ since $\sigma^{N-j}$ is injective.

Now, you can choose a matrix that is simpler to write down, for example $a_{ij} = \sigma^{i-1}(j)$ will yield

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &\ldots & N-1 & N\\
2 & 3 &\ldots & N & 1\\
\vdots &\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
N-1& N &\ldots &N - 3& N-2\\
N& 1&\ldots &N-2&N-1
\end{pmatrix}
& \tag{1}\end{align}

and to see it won't have repeating entries you just repeat the above argumentation.

To get more explicit, $\sigma^k(l) = (k + l - 1)\pmod N + 1$ where $$x\mapsto x\!\!\!\!\pmod N\colon\, \Bbb Z\to \{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}$$ is interpreted as operator assigning remainder of $x$ when divided by $N$.

**Edit:** I claim that the solution $(1)$ is *essentially* still good even after the question was altered. Let me elaborate.

Let $N = 2n+1$. I claim that $F(N) \leq n$. First notice that $F(N) = k+1$ means that there exists matrix $(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{n+1,j}\neq 1$ for $n+1-k\leq j \leq n+1+k$. Now, if $F(N)>n$, that means that there exists a matrix $(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{n+1,j}\neq 1$ for $$n+1-(F(n)-1)\leq j \leq n+1+(F(n) - 1)$$ but since $n+1-(F(n)-1)\leq 1$ and $n+1+(F(n)-1)\geq N$, that means that $(a_{ij})$ does not have $1$ in $(n+1)$-st row. But that means that $(n+1)$-st row has repeating entry by Pigeonhole principle. Contradiction.

All it remains is to show that $F(N) = n$ by giving a matrix with non-repeating entries in rows or columns in which distance of $1$ from center is not smaller than $n$. I claim that $(1)$ is *essentially* that matrix - all we have to do is switch $1$ with $n+1$ wherever they occur.

The question is on which entries does $n+1$ occur?

$$\sigma^{i-1}(j) = n+1 \iff \sigma^{N+1-i}(n+1) = j \iff j = (N+1-i + n+1 - 1)\pmod N + 1 \\ \iff j = (n+1-i)\pmod N + 1$$

*Case 1.* For $i\leq n+1$, we get $j = n + 2 - i$ and the distance of $(i,j)$ from the center is $$|(n+1)-i|+|(n+1)-(n+2-i)| = (n+1-i) + (i-1) = n$$

*Case 2.* For $i>n+1$, we get $j= N + n + 2 - i$ and the distance of $(i,j)$ from the center is $$|i-(n+1)|+|(N + n + 2 - i)-(n+1)| = (i - n - 1) + (N + 1 - i) = n+1$$

Finally, let $\tau = (1,\  n+1)\in S_N$. Then the matrix you are looking for is $a_{ij} = (\tau\circ \sigma^{i-1})(j)$.

Comment: I actually need to print the matrix using programming language so can you  help me with the formula to print the number for specific $a [i][j]$ ?

Comment: Just write a double for loop on $i$ and $j$, @sammy

Comment: is there a matrix in which $1$ can be placed farthest from center i.e. not immediate horizontal and vertical cell for $n>=5$

Comment: @sammy, there are a lot different matrices that satisfy your condition, but I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment. What I did in my answer is write down the formula for matrices you wrote down, but there are simpler ways (for example $a_{ij}=\sigma^{i-1}(j)$ will start with row $(1\,2\,\ldots\, N)$, the next one will be $(2\,3\,\ldots\, N\, 1)$ etc.).

Comment: I mean that the matrix should also satisfy the condition that I just mentioned in problem. Please can you help me out ?

Comment: @sammy, please see my edit. Let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: @Ennar: It seems that all the answers given so far are suddenly wrong, because the OP has altered his question.

Comment: @AlexM., oh, haven't noticed it, thank you.

Comment: @Ennar for $N=5$ according to your answer the $F(5)$ will be $1$ where as$ F(5) is 2 $that is by placing $1$ as away as possible from center of matrix.

Comment: @AlexM. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Please can you help me out ? I'm stuck on this for past few days.

Comment: @sammy, I've answered your original question. Let me think about your edit.

Comment: @Ennar  I'm really sorry for the inconvenience caused. Thanks for helping. It would be great if you could help me out again.

Comment: @sammy, please look at my edit.

Comment: @Ennar is there another solution than your first solution **before edit** because for N=5 your previous solution gives wrong answer. Now the last equation in the edited answer seems different. So is that a new equation ?

Comment: @sammy, it seems we have trouble communicating. I clearly say that the solution to the previous question is *essentially* solution to the new question, all we have to do is switch places of $1$ and $n+1$. So, yes, the last equation is different from the first one since I switched places of $1$ and $n+1$. I'm not sure what you are misunderstanding. And my first solution *is not wrong*. Your question was. You cannot alter questions and say: "Look, your solution is wrong now." That is just rude.

Comment: @Ennar No I didn't mean it like that. I'm just confused. I'm really sorry. I now get what you meant. The problem is with notation. So how do I print the matrix now ? Earlier I was using $ a[i][j] = (i+j-2) (mod N) +1 $. So all I have to do is switch $1$ with $n+1$ in the matrix ? I'm just confused.

Comment: @sammy, "If $(i+j-2)\pmod N + 1 = 1$, then $a[i][j] = n + 1$, else if $(i+j-2)\pmod N + 1 = n+1$, then $a[i][j] = 1$, else $a[i][j] = (i+j-2)\pmod N + 1$."

Comment: @Ennar Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm temporarily deleting this answer because the question is from an ongoing contest. Sorry.